# Can two resonance structures of a molecule have different cas numbers?

Tags: nomenclature, resonance

From [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_(chemistry)#Resonance_vs_isomerism) :

> Specifically, when a molecular structure is said to be represented by a resonance hybrid, it does not mean that electrons of the molecule are "resonating" or shifting back and forth between several sets of positions, each one represented by a Lewis structure. Rather, it means that the set of contributing structures represents an intermediate structure (a weighted average of the contributors), with a single, well-defined geometry and distribution of electrons. It is incorrect to regard resonance hybrids as rapidly interconverting isomers, even though the term "resonance" might evoke such an image.

Therefore, one should never treat two resonance structures of a molecule as distinct substances, right?

Well, here is an example of (what appear to be) two resonance structures of a molecule, which however have each a distinct cas number, different name, and are even sold separately (different catalogue number) by a single vendor:

https://www.combi-blocks.com/cgi-bin/find.cgi?HC-3087
273-13-2
[image]

https://www.combi-blocks.com/cgi-bin/find.cgi?JH-8440
22706-22-5
[image]

**How can this be explained?**

**Is the attribution of distinct cas numbers to resonance structures of a molecule 'allowed' or 'correct', for some reason, despite the fact that they point to the exact same chemical entity? Or have they just got it wrong in this case?**

**Do you know of any other examples of resonance structures of a molecule being assigned distinct cas numbers?**